# Is the cursor of type "masked color" used anymore?

Tags: mouse-cursor, desktop-duplication

I'm developing a screen capture tool and managed to make it work, even with mouse cursor support.

The problem is, there's a type of mouse cursor called [DXGI_OUTDUPL_POINTER_SHAPE_TYPE_MASKED_COLOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/ne-dxgi1_2-dxgi_outdupl_pointer_shape_type). 
I was not able to find any cursor of this type, so I cannot test it.

This made me think, is that kind of cursor even used anymore (supported by Windows 8 and newer)? 
Can you show me any example of a cursor like that?

Comment: You might want to check standard pointers, I remember some of them ("precision select" AKA crosshair?) was of some unexpected format.

Comment: @nicke-manarin do you have any update on that? I'm facing exactly same issue now

Comment: @theimowski No, I haven't. Not even the crosshair cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several scenarios where it is used:

1. The Hand/Grab cursor (see `grab`/`grabbing` [here](http://elektronotdienst-nuernberg.de/bugs/cursor.html))
2. The `I` beam when running at >= 150% UI scale

There are possibly more but these are two examples that still exist and are present in Windows 10

Also any software defined cursors could use it if an application sets one.

Comment: I have different results. I am using Win11, though.
1) The hand/grab cursor is of type DXGI_OUTDUPL_POINTER_SHAPE_TYPE_COLOR.
2) The 150% UI scale is not necessary for the I beam to be treated as DXGI_OUTDUPL_POINTER_SHAPE_TYPE_MASKED_COLOR.

Answer (score -1):

I have been dealing with this myself. This pointer seems to pop up more in HDR and 10bit color depth monitors. Other than that, I have no idea.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you have a sample to show? It would be helpful.

Comment: Im sorry i really dont fully understand it myself. Im building some video streaming software right now and I was getting a monochrome mousepointer returned for all my text cursors. That seemed normal. But i have since bought a 10bit 4k monitor. Now I get masked color mouse pointers. I am still trying to get the conversion correct, the XOR doesnt seem to be accurate to what windows does.

So, from me and my colleagues experience, It only is used on 10bit HDR monitors. I dont know what kind of sample you want.

Comment: @vulkur see here for a working example of how to convert the data to ARGB and create a seperate XOR mask suitable for OpenGL rendering: https://github.com/gnif/LookingGlass/blob/22f3cf5ba6993a09fcccced3c063f5c098cdca2d/client/renderers/EGL/cursor.c#L262-L282